# C++ comparación de arrays

Tags: c++, punteros

Necesito hacer llamada en main() como obligatorio.

Disena una función  que devuelva verdadero o falso según dos listas de enteros sean exactamente iguales o no.

mi código es este, pero no estar en bucle en igual(int *l1, int*l2).
si se puede, explícame lo que tengo mal, gracias.

```
#include <iostream>

int Igual(int *l1, int *l2){
bool igual = true;
    int tam;
for(int i=0; i<tam; i++){
   if(l1[i] == l2[i]){
std::cout << "Arrays iguales \n";
    igual=true;
} else {
    std::cout<<"Arrays diferentes \n";
  }
  }
    return 0;
}


int main(){
    int tam1, tam2, x,y,res;
    std::cout<<"Que tamano de l1 quiere? \n";
    std::cin>>tam1;
    int l1[tam1];
    std::cout<<"Introduzca todos los numeros para l1 \n";
    for(int i=0;i<tam1; i++){
        std::cin>>x;
        l1[i]=x;
    }
    
    std::cout<<"Que tamano de l2 quiere? \n";
    std::cin>>tam2;
    int l2[tam2];
    std::cout<<"Introduzca todos los numeros para l2 \n";
    for(int j=0;j<tam1; j++){
        std::cin>>y;
        l2[j]=y;
     }
    res=Igual(&l1[0], &l2[0]); }
```

Comment: Nunca pones igual como falso en caso de que sean diferentes. De hecho, tendrias que ponerlo en falso y parar el loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Cómo sabe el compilador el tamaño que van a tener los arrays?

```
int tam;
for(int i=0; i<tam; i++){
```

Fíjate que aquí no le has dado ningún valor a `tam`. Es una variable sin inicializar y, lo que sucede en estos casos, es que tiene un valor aleatorio (básicamente el valor que dejase ahí una variable anterior que ya no existe)

En tu caso cada array va a tener un tamaño diferente, así lo has programado dejando que
el usuario elija tanto el tamaño de `l1` como el de `l2`, entonces tu función debe recibir ambos valores:

```
int igual(int*l1, int tam1, int*l2, int tam2)
```

Quizá la regla más sencilla que permita diferenciar los dos arrays es que sus tamaños sean distintos:

```
if( tam1 != tam2 )
    igual = false;
else
{
    // ...
}
```

Vale, si vamos al `else` entonces es que `tam1` y `tam2` tienen el mismo valor, luego podemos usar cualquiera de los dos para recorrer los arrays y comprobar si son iguales:

```
for( int i=0; i<tam1; i++ )
{
    if( l1[i] != l2[i] )
    {
        igual = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Nota que asumimos que los dos arrays son iguales y, obviamente, dejarán de serlos en el momento en el que encontremos una diferencia. Una vez localizada dicha diferencia no tiene sentido seguir buscando, pues ya sabemos que no son iguales.

Juntándolo todo quedaría así:

```
int son_iguales(int*l1, int tam1, int*l2, int tam2)
{
    bool igual = true;

    if( tam1 != tam2 )
        igual = false;
    else
    {
        for( int i=0; i<tam1; i++ )
        {
            if( l1[i] != l2[i] )
            {
                igual = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return igual;
}
```

Fíjate que aquí no estamos mostrando ningún mensaje. A la hora de programar, cada función debe tener una responsabilidad única (por tu bien), en el caso de esta función, su responsabilidad es determinar si los arrays son iguales o no, ya está.

¿Dónde mostramos el mensaje entonces? Bueno, para eso tenemos el `main`:

```
if( son_iguales(l1, tam1, l2, tam2) )
{
    std::cout << "Los arrays son iguales\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Los arrays son diferentes\n";
}
```

Por otro lado, esto es un VLA

```
int tam1;
int l1[tam1];  // <<--- VLA
```

Es algo que ya he explicado incontables veces en este foro. Si buscas VLA en el buscador encontrarás muchas preguntas y respuestas al respecto.

El caso, lo que nos importa, es que no es una característica soportada por el lenguaje. Es decir, si te funciona es porque tu compilador lo soporta, pero no es algo que debas usar pues puede dejar de funcionarte en cualquier otra máquina (o al actualizar el compilador).

Si el tamaño es una variable, usa memoria dinámica:

```
int* l1 = new int[tam1];
```

La única diferencia ahora es que hay que acordarse de liberar la memoria reservada cuando ya no sea necesaria (en este caso antes de finalizar la función `main`:

```
delete[] l1;
```

El último error que he encontrado es al rellenar `l2`. Estás usando `tam1` en vez de `tam2`:

```
std::cout<<"Que tamano de l2 quiere? \n";
std::cin>>tam2;
int l2[tam2]; // <<--- otro VLA. Usas tam2
std::cout<<"Introduzca todos los numeros para l2 \n";
for(int j=0;j<tam1; j++){ // <<--- tam1
    std::cin>>y;
    l2[j]=y;
 }
```

Si `tam1 < tam2` entonces no vas a rellenar todo el array. Si `tam1 > tam2` acabarás escribiendo fuera del array y sobreescribiendo otras variables de tu programa (o peor, intentando escribir en memoria que no te pertenece, lo que hace que el compilador mate tu programa para que no corrompa la memoria de otros procesos).

Y para finalizar, por favor, tabula correctamente el código y usa nombres de variables que den alguna idea acerca de la finalidad de cada variable. Si no cumples estas dos normas básicas tus programas serán ilegibles

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora me compila todo y entendí lo que me faltaba.